# Official resources about disc management on linux / distributions

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage, disk, distributions

My question is about official linux and common distributions (e.g. fedora/debian) on learning disk management in practice on linux / linux distributions. The layout, may be including the file system, although my focus here is not the theory/technology behind the implementation but the practical usage. For example, when I install a distribution (say Fedora), it asks me (now it is mostly automated but I'd like to do it myself or at lest know what's going on) about whether I want to creat boot, home etc partitions and then apparently it creates some more (probably "virtual" but I don't know how). I'd like to know about that whole process, for example if I install different distributions, is the /boot directory shared by all? Why are different types of file system recommended for different partitions? What are the differences? Tools to probe and manage the disk usage and file system (df, fdisk, parted etc) and so on..

I mostly search on the web but the information is very scattered and mostly shallow. Which is the most appropriate/updated resource to look for for this kind of stuff? Again, my focus in this is not so much on Linux kernel internals as the usage but with depth. Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever tried to read [help/on-topic]? It clearly states that learning materials are of topic. So you might not have such a rule for banning, but U&L has. That there is no other place to ask is no excuse, there is a lot of stuff you (fortunately) cannot ask about on the web without the result of being legally prosecuted, and U&L is no place for the latter either.

Comment: Ooops sorry I meant to write I haven't seen such a rule not I haven't such a rule. That was a typo, my mistake. Thanks for pointing to the help center. Do you mean the help center of the distribution? For example on my Fedora I have GNOME Help. Is it what you are referring to?

Comment: Click the link. It is the help center for this site.

Comment: Oh.. I am sorry I hadn't seen that. I don't want to break the rules. I'll modify the question to limit it to request for official documentation sources (not sure if they exist though). I won't mind if a moderator closes it either. Or is it more appropriate to delete the question altogether?

Comment: @Anthon Edited out the book parts. Thanks for your time and patience in pointing the error. This is a great website and I am more than happy to follow the rules!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I read the rules and it does seem to indicate open ended questions like this are not encouraged.

Here is a quick link to them: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help

However in case it is allowed, I would suggest reading Linux CompTIA or any of the very popular certification courseware. You will need more than just the understanding of disks to become conversant with how to design a partition scheme.

Things like the purpose of the box, what kind of network is it in (in case of NAS/SAN etc), and I am sure there are many more questions that would require an understanding of before you could properly "know" what to design.

PS I would assume this question will be deleted as it is an opinion and could be seen as an open ended question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Do you mean the books for the preparation of Linux CompTIA  exam? I just did a quick google search and it sounds like a good place to start. Thanks!

Comment: yes, or something similar, they all seem to be pretty good